# Stream sorted method with comparator

Tags: java, java-stream, method-reference

I don't understand why *code1* works but *code2* doesn't compile. Please explain.

```
//Code1:
    Stream<String> s = Stream.of("AA", "BB");
    s.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .forEach(System.out::print);

//Code2:
    Stream<String> s = Stream.of("AA", "BB");
    s.sorted(Comparator::reverseOrder)
            .forEach(System.out::print);
```

The difference between the two is *code1* uses `Comparator.reverseOrder()` while *code2* uses `Comparator::reverseOrder`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message from the compiler should tell you that.

`sorted()` expects a Comparator instance. `Comparator.reverseOrder()`returns a Comparator instance. So that works fine.

`Comparator::reverseOrder` is a method reference to the reverseOrder() method of Comparator. So your code basically says: each time you need to compare two strings, pass them as argument to `Comparator.reverseOrder` to compare them. But that can't possibly work. This method takes nothing as argument, and returns a Comparator. So it doesn't match the signature of a `Comparator<String>`, which is supposed to take two Strings as argument, and return an integer.

If you had a method such as

```
class Foo
    public static int compareStrings(String s1, String s2) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you could use

```
sorted((s1, s2) -> Foo.compareStrings(s1, s2))
```

which you can transform, using a method reference, to

```
sorted(Foo::compareStrings)
```

Because compareStrings, just like the unique abstract method of `Comparator<String>`, takes two Strings as argument and returns an int.

Answer (score 7):

Because the first example is a `factory-method` so when you inspect it, you see that you get a comparator back.

But the second one is a `method-reference` which you could write like this:

```
Stream<String> s = Stream.of("AA", "BB");
s.sorted(() -> Comparator.reverseOrder()) // no semantic difference!
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

But it has a whole different meaning because this time you are given `Stream#sorted()` a `Supplier<Comparator<?>>` but it just needs a `Comparator<?>`

**Small Sidenote:** Don't store streams in variables, use them directly. So i would suggest you just write:

```
Stream.of("AA", "BB")
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```